# Ubuntu : apt-get command error

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I work with Ubuntu 10.04 everyday. Several days ago, when I release command sudo apt-get install .... it run very good, no error. I also able to open websites with my browser with no proxy.

But, today, I got error. Every time I release the command, the connection redirected to an IP in my local network. I can see it in the terminal window.

Several days ago I tried to connect to the internet throught the IP, by SSH tunneling. But I forget what I have done and there is no way home.

This is the output in terminal :

```
deo@deo-laptop:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for deo: 
Err http://cx.archive.ubuntu.com lucid Release.gpg                             [
Could not connect to 10.7.7.15:3128 (10.7.7.15). - connect (110: Connection timed out)
Err http://cx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/main Translation-en_US          
Unable to connect to 10.7.7.15:3128:
```

10.7.7.15 is an adress in my local network. Somebody please help me :)

Comment: That's your local proxy server. Contact the network administrator.

Comment: Thanks Michael. But now I am not working in my office, I work at home with a single computer now.

Comment: oops, sorry. Finally, I have found my mistakes. several days ago I set system proxy (System->preferences->Network Proxies) to the IP address and now I have reset it. And Viola, everything works well. Thanks's friend !